# Dynamic telerik TabStrip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, tabs, telerik, strip

I'm working on a dynamic Telerik Tab Strip.

Each tab have a Grid and I need to pass a parameter to the action for filter my model but that parameter is allways null.

View:

```
     @{ Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
            .Name("TabStripDetailArticle")
            .Items(tabstrip =>
                {

        //Know how Many Zones are there
            var zones = Model.Articles.GroupBy(e => e.Zone);

        //For each Zone I need a Tab,
                foreach (var inZone in zones)
                {
                    tabstrip.Add()
                        .Text(inZone.Key)
                        .Content(() =>
                                     {
                    //On each tab there's a Grid and I need to pass the zone to filter my model.
                                         @Html.Action("TabStripSelected", Controllers.Valoration, new { idZone = inZone.Key });
                                     });
                 }

        }
        )

        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .Render();
}
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult TabStripSelected(string idZone)
    {

       return PartialView("_GridArticlesByZone",CurrentHvm.Articles.Where(e => e.Zone == idZone));

    }
```

I would like to know if ther's another way to do that, or if I'm missing something.

Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem! :)

Controller:

```
  foreach (var inZone in zones)
                {
                     //!! Missing!
                    **IGrouping<string, Article> zone = inZone;**
                    tabstrip.Add()
                        .Text(inZone.Key)
                        .Content(() =>
                                     {
                                         @Html.Action("TabStripSelected", Controllers.Valoration, new { id = **zone.Key** });
                                     });
                 }
```

Thank's!